# Python IMAPClient fetch() method optimization for large data

Tags: python, imap, imaplib, imapclient

I am  writing an email client using [IMAPClient](https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). My goal now is to render the list of messages in my INBOX. The number of messages amount to around 4 thousand. The problem is that it takes ages to fetch these letters like this:

```
server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)    
server.select_folder('INBOX')
messages = server.search(['NOT DELETED'])
response = server.fetch(messages, ['RFC822', 'BODY[TEXT]']) # TAKES AGES TO FINISH
```

It seem intuitive that I should ask for, say, the first 20 messages, and then if the user scrolls down, ask for the next chunk of 20 messages (sorted by date when the letter has been received). In other words, I should somehow *paginate* the `fetch` command, or make it lazy. But IMAPClient seems to be silent on this , though it seems like a major issue. Any ideas ?

Comment: Presumably messages is a list.  Break it into sublists!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to break up `messages` into chunks and just request the messages you need at the time.

In order to quickly build a message list for display to the user, you might want to consider requesting `ENVELOPE` for all messages first. IMAP servers are generally optimised for this and the `ENVELOPE` response is much smaller than the `RFC822` or `BODY[TEXT]` responses.